# Laravel how to use isset $_GET

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want display the layouts.layout if the value of  $_GET['actionboard'] isset, I mean If the actionboard value is got it should display the layouts.layouts.

How can i do this in laravel way.

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['actionboard'])){ ?>
@extends('layouts.layouts')
@section('body')
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: How about you take a look into the laravel docs? http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests `Input::has('actionboard')`

Answer (score 1):

Pass the Input reference to the view like this:

```
//In your controller
View::share('actionboard', Input::get('actionboard'));
```

Then use the variable in the view:

```
//In your view
<?php if($actionboard){ ?>
@extends('layouts.layouts')
@section('body')
<?php } ?>
```